# How can I install the NVIDIA driver on CentOS kernel 4.18.0

Tags: centos, rhel, drivers, nvidia

When I try to install the NVIDIA driver on my CentOS 8 with kernel 4.18.0 I get the following error in the logfile:

`error: implicit declaration of function 'drm_pci_init';`

Comment: Please edit your question and include the command you are running which is producing this error.

Comment: @Panki It's the installation package, which in my case was called "NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.108.run" but it could be called differently when other people install other versions, or it could be "nvidia-install" when people unpack the installation first. So that's not really important for the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll start from the very beginging. First you have to install the developer packages and some other packages:

```
dnf groupinstall "Development Tools"
dnf install libglvnd-devel elfutils-libelf-devel
```

Then disable the nuveau-driver, if installed

```
grub2-editenv - set "$(grub2-editenv - list | grep kernelopts) nouveau.modeset=0"
```

You could also remove the driver package alltogether:

```
dnf remove xorg-x11-drv-nouveau
```

Now reboot to a command line. X11 and everything using OpenGL must not be running.

You have to download an older driver for which there is a patch. In my case the newest version was v108, but you need v107. Either get it via the NVIDIA homepage or with wget:

```
# Download the driver
wget https://de.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/340.107/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.107.run
# Unpack the driver, do not install
bash NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.107.run --extract-only
cd NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.107/
# Get the patch from pastebin, or the NVIDIA developer forum (link below)
wget https://pastebin.com/raw/qsqxsBmZ -O patch_340.107.diff
# Apply the patch to the 
patch -l -p0 < patch_340.107.diff

# If you have another kernel version of course you have to change the path accordingly
./nvidia-installer -a --kernel-source-path /usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-240.10.1.el8_3.x86_64/
```

The patch comes from this forum entry: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/solved-nvidia-340-107-linux-5-0-rc5-failed-to-build-kernel-module/70277